# MongoDB - Is searching in arrays as fast as searching in plain keys?

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing

Say I've the following design:

```
id | participant_ids
...| [ObjectId(...), ObjectId(...)]
```

Now I'm querying it this way:

```
db.events.find({
    participant_ids: ObjectId(...)
});
```

Which is identical to this:

```
db.events.find({
    participant_ids: {
        $in: ObjectId(...)
    }
});
```

I assume there isn't a difference in performance between those two (but correct me if I'm wrong!).

---

For each event, there are at least 1 and at most 2 participants. So I could also use the following design:

```
id | participant_1_id | participant_2_id
```

... and query it like this ...:

```
db.events.find({
    $or: {
        participant_1_id: ObjectId(...),
        participant_2_id: ObjectId(...)
    }
});
```

---

If I wouldn't use indexing, this probably doesn't really make a difference, but -of course- I am.

For the first design, I'ld go with the following index:

```
db.events.ensureIndex({
    participant_ids: 1
});
```

For the second one, I'ld go with this:

```
db.events.ensureIndex({
    participant_1_id: 1,
    participant_2_id: 1
});
```

---

Both got downsides when you look at their performance.

- **1st query:** Using an `Array` is probably slower than using a plain key.
- **2nd query:** Using the `$or`-operator isn't very fast.
- **2nd query:** Isn't very scalable, say I'ld want to release the limit of participants sometime, that wouldn't be possible (you'd have unlimited keys and unlimited items in the `$or`-part of the queries).

---

My questions are:
- What design should I use?
- Can I index `Array`s? The docs don't say anything about this, and I'm not sure `Array`s are (since their contents can vary really much).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1st query: Using an Array is probably slower than using a plain key.

I don't think so. It should be the exact same index-based access path if you have one value ("plain key") or multiple ("Array").

`participant_1_id, participant_2_id` is just terrible.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was afraid it would be slower (which could be one reason other rdbs aren't using `Array`s). Great to hear it's just as fast as separate keys (just way more readable).

Comment: Confirmed. There's no performance difference and the array version is quite a bit more flexible.